# Show that $\sigma(f)$ = $\{f^{-1}(F): F \in \Sigma \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ be a set, $(\Xi, \Sigma)$ be a measure space and $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Xi$ a map. Define

$\sigma(f) = \{f^{-1}(F): F \in \Sigma \}.$

Show that $\sigma(f)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

I don't know how to approach this problem since this map doesn't seem to have any properties at all. For example, when I want to show that $\Omega \in \sigma(f)$ is true, I don't see any way to justify this. Why should any pre-image have the desired property to be identical with $\Omega$?

**Edit:**

So with the hints given before, I tried to solve the rest and now would like to have your opinion on it.

> $\emptyset \in \sigma(f):$

Since $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it contains $\emptyset$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(\emptyset) \in \Omega$, and it's value is obviously $\emptyset$ itself.

> $A, B \in \sigma(f) \Rightarrow A \setminus B \in \sigma(f):$

If $A, B \in \sigma(f)$, then there exist $F, G \in \Sigma$ such that $f(A) = F $ and $f(B) = G$. Furthermore, we have $f(A) \setminus f(B) \in \Sigma$, and thus, $f^{-1}(f(A) \setminus f(B)) = f^{-1}(f(A)) \setminus f^{-1}(f(B)) = A \setminus B \in \Omega.$

> $A_1, A_2, \ ... \in \sigma(f) \Rightarrow \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k \in \sigma(f):$

If $A_1, A_2, \ ... \in \sigma(f)$, then there exist $F_1, F_2, \ ... \in \Sigma$ such that $f(A_1) = F_1, f(A_2) = F_2, \ ... \in \Sigma$, and thus, $\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty F_k \in \Sigma$. Hence, $\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty f^{-1}(F_k) = \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k \in \sigma(f).$

Comment: Check that $\omega\in f^{-1}(f(\omega))$, so $\Omega=f^{-1}(\Xi)$. For other properties for $\sigma$-algebra, check that, for example, $f^{-1}(\cup_\alpha X_\alpha)=\cup_\alpha f^{-1}(X_\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess $f^{-1}$ doesn't mean the invers but the preimage of f.
So $f^{-1}(F)$ is the set of all $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $f(\omega) \in F$.

Because $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra it holds $\Xi \in \Sigma$ so $f^{-1}(\Xi) \in \sigma(f)$.
But the preimage of the whole image space is the whole preimage space, so $f^{-1}(\Xi) = \Omega$.

That's why $\Omega \in \sigma(f)$…

Try the rest by yourself!